# How to build a production only angular 9 docker image

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

I am not much into frontend development. I am building a docker image for the angular 9 application. Here is something I tried.

```
ARG NODE_VERSION=12.16.1

# stage - # 1
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-buster-slim as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install --only=production && npm run build --prod

# stage - #final
FROM nginx:stable

COPY --from=builder /webapp/dist/webapp /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY demo-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I am getting the following error.

```
#10 5.883 > webapp@0.0.0 build /webapp
#10 5.883 > ng build
#10 5.883 
#10 5.885 sh: 1: ng: not found
#10 5.887 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
#10 5.887 npm ERR! syscall spawn
#10 5.887 npm ERR! file sh
#10 5.887 npm ERR! errno ENOENT
#10 5.888 npm ERR! webapp@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
#10 5.888 npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
#10 5.888 npm ERR! 
#10 5.888 npm ERR! Failed at the webapp@0.0.0 build script.
#10 5.888 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
#10 5.892
```

when I do the production only `npm install` the "ng" command is not being installed to the first phase of the image. If I do not use with the --only=production then all the dev dependencies are installed along with it.
How can I only get the production only dependencies, yet build it for production ?
Does the `npm run build --prod` command create a /dist folder only containing the production files ?
How to do it correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

This is working file :

```
ARG NODE_VERSION=12.16.1

# stage - # 1
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-buster-slim as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install 
RUN npm run build --prod

# stage - #final
FROM nginx:stable

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/{add_angularapp_name}  /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but I was looking for a concrete answer. I could easily done my job and call it a day. I know the error happened because of the --production switch.  why do `npm install` have a switch in that case, if `ng build --prod` will do it ? I am missing something here and I am after that answer.